# Android Studio second window open

Tags: android-studio

[image]Each time i open a project in android studio, it opens a second window like imn the screenshot below.

Comment: Q: When did this start?  Q: Are you able to reproduce the problem with any project?  Have you tried creating a brand new project?  Q: Failing all else, have you considered uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio?

Comment: Got same issue, probably started after I clicked 'Flutter commands: Open for Editing in Android Studio' in topbar after opening file in android sub-folder. Then things go just messy: exceptions, UI bugs, gradle runnings, and unresponsive additional windows with android project. Android studio 3.5.3. Still looking how to get rid of this...

Comment: Yes it happens even when creating a new project. The second window actually opens to the android folder while the primary window opens to the project itself like normally. I have uninstalled and reinstalled and still the same thing.

Comment: Got the issue fixed. Not sure what the exact issue was that caused the extra window all the time but it's fixed. When uninstalling Android Studio, it wasn't deleting the preferences folder at "C:/users/<username folder>/.AndroidStudio3.5" folder apparently so I deleted it and re-opened android studio and it all works accordingly now.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Android Studio 3.6 RC1 but issue still there. Then went to Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter and unchecked Experiments options that I turned on some time ago and voila, problem go away.